# Testing an Angular service in Jasmine using Subject and localstorage

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have a login page I need to test, which uses an authentication service. Roughly speaking, when the login button is pressed, at some point this occurs :

```
  this.userService.$authentification.subscribe((res)=>{
    if(res.success){
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    }else{
      console.error(res.error.code)
      this.error=res.error;
    }
  })
  this.userService.authentification(login, pwd);
```

(this is part of the code I am supposed to test and therefore I should ideally not modify it)

Internally, $authentification is a Subject :

```
$authentification = new Subject<any>();
```

which is attached to the service method authentification :

```
  authentification(login : string, password : string){
    let body = {
      login: login,
      password: password
    }
    this.jwtLocalstorage.remove();
    let post = this.http.post<any>(environment.api + 'user/login/index.php', body, {}).subscribe(response => {
      post.unsubscribe();
      if(response.jwt){
        this.jwtLocalstorage.add(response.jwt, response.data.id);
        this.$authentification.next({
          success:true,
          error: null
        });
      }else{
        this.$authentification.next({
          success:false,
          error: {code:"0X"}
        });
      }
    },response => {
      post.unsubscribe();
      this.$authentification.next({
        success:false,
        error: response.error
      });
    });
  }
```

The service calls up the authentication API, stores the results in the local storage, and then feeds a confirmation in the Subject object, which will then be used by the login page to decide what to do next.

When testing the login page, what am I supposed to simulate here? Should I mock the service, subject and local storage, or get the service from the component and then mock the subject and local storage? I'm not quite sure how to proceed here.

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing is about testing a unit of code. **Everything outside of this unit should be mocked**.

So yes, you should mock your service. From there, think about it : since you have mocked the service, why should you mock anything else in it ? A mock has no dependency, so just mock the service and nothing else.

Here is the simplest mock you can make to test your code

```js
const state = new Subject<any>();
serviceMock: any = {
  $authentification: state.asObservable(),
  authentification: jasmine.createSpy()
};
```

From there, simply inject this mock in your component

```js
component = new MyComponent(serviceMock);
```

And now, make a meaningful test

```js
it('Should redirect in case of success', (done) => {

  state.pipe(first()).subscribe(() => {
    expect(component.router.navigate)
      .toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(['/dashboard']);
    done();
  });

  component.yourFunctionToCallToTest();

  state.next({ success: true });
});
```